# SwifSocket Outgoing port

Tags: ios, sockets, tcp

I'm creating a function for ios app which will send a file to a server.
As for now I'm testing to send a simple string message to a TCP server downloaded on APPStore. Connection and send string is working and I've notice it generate a random outgoing port(the app i downloaded has a console which displays the ip address and port where the message comes from). My target server was created by other which only accepts 1 specific port(as the designed requires).

Is there a way to set the outgoing port on iOS development?
Currently im using the swiftsocket https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket

Is there an API for ios will let me do this?

Comment: It would be very unusual for a server to require a specific source port.  That library doesn't seem to let you set the source port. You could use the Network framework which is a more modern low-level network framework. It lets you specify the source port via the client's `NWEndpoint`

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11!

Comment: Hi @Paulw11. Is it possible to send data(files) using the NWConnection and NWEndpoint?

Comment: It is a low-level socket framework. You can build anything you like on top of it.